# Sub-menu in css drop down disappears before Hover when menu wraps according to width

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with Drop down menu. When the content of navigation wraps according to its width and the situation when menu items stacks on one another, at this time the sub menu appears at a certain distance from it and disappears before i hover on it. Help! I am working on this code. Fiddle is linked below.

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-option1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-option2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu3</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
    nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
nav ul { 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-table;
}
nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
nav ul li:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%, #5f6975 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4f5964 0%,#5f6975 40%);
}
nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
    color: #757575; text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul ul {
    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
}
nav ul ul li {
    float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
    padding: 15px 40px;
    color: #fff;
}   
nav ul ul li a:hover {
    background: #4b545f;
}
nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; left: 100%; top:0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sagarguhe/xhABB/2/)

Comment: Your example seems to be working fine for me in chrome - 'sub-option1' wraps but it can hover over it.

Comment: yes, it works fine but when then resolution of screen changes and main category also wraps this causes problem. for example, in fiddle drag the vertical partition to right until the menu items wrap to next line.

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions for this.

**Solution 1**

Set the **width** of the main **UL** element. So the menu wont break on resize.

---

**Solution 2**

Set the sizes in percentages or em, especially the **font-size**, so that everything will be scalable and easy to resize.

---

**Solution 3 (optional)**

Use responsive design, and adjust menu for different resolutions (460 - 760, 760 - 960, 1000+). This calls for more work, but its a bigger payoff. :)